# Android Button Onclick closes application

Tags: android, events, button, onclick

```
btnPhotoGalary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_photo_galary);
btnPhotoGalary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                AllPhotoActivity.class));
    }
});


btnInformation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_information);
btnInformation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                Information.class));
    }
});
```

This code is for a button's click event. The Information button shows in the application, but when you click it the application closes automatically. Why?

Comment: can you explain your question clearly ?

Comment: stacktrace or it didn't happen.

Comment: you have problem within `AllPhotoActivity.class` and `Information.class` Activities

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside onclick method. Then check weather control comes inside or not.

Comment: There is problem with time of click. When clicking button Gallery works normally, but time of click Information button application closed. How I can create button which work?

Comment: edit your post with `Information.class` code.

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace of this error?

Comment: @Mandro if you mean the app crash, can you paste your log cat error message ?

Comment: @Mandro : you have bug in `Information.class` Acitivity edit your post with this Activity code

Comment: Time of click AllPhotoActivity.class works normally, but Information.class then don`t work. Write sample code I write on Information.java then test this.

Comment: Post your crash logs. Also check that you have added the Activity containing Information class to your Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
btnPhotoGalary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_photo_galary);
    btnPhotoGalary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,
                    AllPhotoActivity.class));
        }
    });


    btnInformation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_information);
    btnInformation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,
                    Information.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: well atleast i tryed :) give more info and il try again :p

Answer (score 0):

The code is looking fine...

You should paste the error description here. It can be copy from DDMS window.

**Checklist:**

Check the Manifest file, have you defined your activity in the XML?

```
<activity android:name=".AllPhotoActivity" android:label="Photo Activity Title"> 
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. This is problem of Maifest I forget about this add there activity :)

Comment: Recommendation: call finish(); function after StartActivity. it popups last activity from stack.